# Why are braces after a for() loop statement making my code behave different?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
int n,t,i;
cout<<"input a number"<<endl;
cin>>n;
for(i=1;i<=10;++i)
t=n*i;
cout<<t<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

here if I input 10 on console screen then the the output I get is just 100,
while below when I input then the I get the whole table of 10 on my console. I don't understand what stopped my above code to show the below output. Was it the `return`?

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
int n,t,i;
cout<<"input a number"<<endl;
cin>>n;
for(i=1;i<=10;++i)
{
t=n*i;
cout<<t<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

in this I get whole table until 10. Why is that?

Comment: Because in the first example `t=n*i;` is the only statment in the loop body. `cout<<t<<endl;` will execute 1 time after the loop ends.

Comment: I indented the code, now it should be more clear

Comment: @bibi The improper indentation is part of the question in this case. Rolled back your edit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ fair enough

Comment: @OP -- Please indent your code properly, then you don't have issues like this   (for some odd reason, I have seen a lot of new programmers write with the code flushed to the left.  Since so many are doing it, I would be curious as to where they're picking up this practice from,).

Comment: Better to always use braces for if/while/for statements - along with indenting your code. Makes things very clear

Comment: The question you are asking is about the very basics of C++ language. It indicates that you need to read a good book on C++ to develop understanding of basic concepts. It is not something that can be learned properly by asking narrow-scope questions on the Internet. And what is `<iostream.h>`, BTW?

Comment: @AnT - OP is more than likely using the outdated, ancient, Turbo C++ compiler.

Answer (score 6):

If you indent your code properly, you can see the the first for loop only executes one statement:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int n,t,i;
    cout<<"input a number"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=10;++i)
        t=n*i; // Executed within for loop
    cout<<t<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

while

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int n,t,i;
    cout<<"input a number"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=10;++i)
    {  // Every statement within the scope block is executed in the for loop
        t=n*i;
        cout<<t<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any conditional or loop construct (`if`,`else`,`for`,`while`,`do`) followed by a single statement will only execute that statement, if it's followed by a scope block (`{}`) all statements within the scope block will be executed.

Comment: Re: "all statements within the scope block will be executed" -- and that's because the block **is** a single statement. That is, `if (true)` executes the statement that follows it.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(i=1;i<=10;++i)
t=n*i;
cout<<t<<endl;
```

is equivalent to:

```
for(i=1;i<=10;++i) {
    t=n*i;
}
cout<<t<<endl;
```

so, the first snippet computes `t = n * i` 10 times, but prints only last evaluation of `t` due to `cout<<t<<endl;` that is placed outside the loop.